# c# asynchronous server/client. Socket (on client side) disconnects "randomly"

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

this is my first post here so please be gentle =)

I'm writing an asynchronuos server/client application for the management of a DB for my office, i tested it locally on my computer and it worked fine. When I uploaded the server tool on another machine I found something that is driving me crazy: the server/client handle only the first query, when I send another query both server and client crash.

After going through lines in debug mode I found the problem: after the beginconnect() (during the second query) the socket is connected but when the debugger reaches the beginsend() line the socket is disconnected (this happens only on client side, the socket on server side seems connected).

I can't figure how it can happen, the socket is re-instantiated every time I send a new query and of course is shutted down and disposed after the query process (send/receive) is completed. My idea is that the disposal of the socket doesn't happen immediately but after a while (but why always between the new beginconnect() and beginsend()?). Do you have any clue on this? Or I should reserve a room in a mental hospital?

*** NEW PART (EDITED) ***

well..here again! This time the socket on client side remains open for the entire session (socket closure occurs only on client tool closure) but i receive another kind of error: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)"
After some googling I discovered that this kind of error is generally triggered by the server on the other side of the connection so I tryed to "mine" server code lines to figure where this connection closure command is. I found that the problem may be in the following piece of code:

```
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("send callback");
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("\nQuery answer sent to client");

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            //handler.Disconnect(true);
            //handler.Dispose();
            state.content = new List<byte[]>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

deleting the handler.shutdown line the client is no more able to detect the end of transmission (not a real problem,  is the last part of the sent packet so it is possible to use that as trigger..at least I think). Any suggestion? I read something about the keepalive but I can't understand how to set it and if it is really necessary in this situation. Thanks in advance for all your effort.

Comment: Have you considered using a network library such as networkcomms.net? This might save you a fair bit of time on the networking side. There is a good example of it in action here http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I already wrote my personal library for the com protocol and I hope to fix it, also to understand how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to open and close sockets like you do.
Keep a socket open if possible, because it needs to get freed by your program and the OS.

Comment: I tryed this approach, and I have just a little question about it..if I try to disconnect the socket after the send/receive (without disposing it, just disconnecting it) operation I receive the socket disconnected error message at the same point. This could be an error linked to the bad management of the socket..suggestion?

Comment: The whole point is more that sockets might have delays to be disconnected on the Windows/operating system layer, thus it is not recommended to disconnect/dispose. If you implement this, then it gets complicated to handle the time until a disconnected socket gets available again.

Comment: So I should directly leave it open and connected? The problem is that I don't know how long an user can look at the query result (minutes or hours..) so the socket could stay connected for long time..does this situation affect the server operations? (it should accept up to 10 connections). Maybe I didn't understand weel how sockets work...

Comment: 10 parallel connections should be no problem at all. I like this description here: "TCP is a bidirectional protocol. Think about it like a conversation between two people. It’s rude for one person to simply stop talking and walk away. Proper social protocol requires that the person who is done talking wait and listen to what the other person has to say before walking away. One side starts winding down the conversation — “Well, it’s been nice, but I have to go.” — then politely waits for the other person to finish and agree to finish. (“Yes, okay, I’ll see you later.”)"

Comment: Ok your explanations were very useful. Thanks a lot and let's hope that all will be fixed...i'll let you know.

Comment: Are firewalls involved - sometimes they close a connection after there is no activitz over a longer period. Thus it might help to introduce a "ping"/keepalive message with the sole purpose of having activity to know that both sides are still connected.

Comment: Let me see if I understood well..I should ping the server every X seconds. So I have to write a thread that check the elapsed time since the last connection and when this timespan reach a certain value the thread send a ping to the server to maintain the connection active. This process avoid the timeout disconnection right?
But..how long should the timespan be (those X seconds I mentioned before)?